# Using typedef for vector of pointers in template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a code

```
typedef vector<Tree *> kids_tree;
```

in Tree.cpp

I want to create a template code with typename DataType in TTree.inc

I tried

```
template <typename DataType>
std::vector<TTree<DataType> *> kids_tree;
```

but when I do these

```
kids = kids_tree();
Or
for (kids_tree::size_type i = 0; i < rhs.kids.size(); i++)
```

It throws an error "Use of variable template 'kids_tree' requires template arguments"

Would you please help me with this issue? How should I declare typedef of vector pointer in template class?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Your template declares/defines a *variable* template, not a type-alias template.

For type-aliases you must use `typedef` or `using`:

```
template<typename DataType>
using kids_tree = std::vector<TTree<DataType>*>;
```

With that said, once you have a template, you mist provide a template argument. The symbol `kids_tree` by itself isn't a type, it's a *template* of a type. `kids_tree<int>` is a type.